# Invoke error jQuery ajax callback from within servlet

Tags: java, jquery, servlets

Within my ajax call if an error is received I have an alert :

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "myUrl",       
        type: 'POST',
        dataType : "text",
        data : ({
            json : myJson
        }),
        success : function(data) {
                 alert('success');
    },
    error : function() {
                alert ('error');
    }
```

From within java is it possible to send back to invoke the error callback in jquery if an exception is thrown. So something like :

```
    try {
        PrintWriter out = resourceResponse.getWriter();
        out.println("success");
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        PrintWriter out = resourceResponse.getWriter();
        out.println("error");
        out.close();
    }
```

i.e instead of printing "error" on the response, invoke the 'error' callback within the jQuery code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set a `http status code` of something other than `200` to invoke the error callback in jQuery Ajax. You can set a error staus of `500 (which is for Internal Server Error)` like

```
catch (Exception e) {
    resourceResponse.setProperty(resourceResponse.HTTP_STATUS_CODE, "500"); 
    PrintWriter out = resourceResponse.getWriter();
    out.println("error");
    out.close();
}
```

in your `catch` block.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Handle each error in servlet and wrap error/success details within JSON response, as pointed by Cranio
2. Use `HttpServletResponse` to set status code to http 500 (or other error code) and then just handle `error` callback in `jQuery` script

Answer (score 1):

Use your AJAX page to return a JSON object with two values

- the actual data
- the error code

So you can process the error logic in the AJAX page.
This solutions accounts for *custom* errors in your AJAX page, errors in the AJAX call can be handled with your existing code.